# tmux not sourcing config in new windows and panes

Tags: config, tmux

I am currently struggling with `tmux` in `zsh`. I have my `tmux.conf` at home and when I start tmux, the `<C-s>` keybinding which I am using in vim is unbound. But when ever I open a new window or pane, my config file is not used and I keep pausing vim when I try to save. How
I tried tmux killall already. I also tried manually sourcing the files.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Might be terminal settings. If it happens again, see if `stty -ixon` fixes it.

Comment: @melpomene could you elaborate? what does it and do i have to execute it inside or outside of tmux?